# SSHLibrary Retry connection to host

Tags: ssh, robotframework

I am using SSHLibrary 2.0 for Robot. I am trying to open connect to a host using private key, but sometime (not always) the connection does not establish.

Sample code below:

```
index = self.SSHLibrary.open_connection(host)
self.SSHLibrary.login_with_public_key(username,passkey, password`)
```

Is there a way to force a connection retry at least one more time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword [Wait until keyword succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds), which will retry a keyword several times until it succeeds or times out.

Comment: Isnt there some way to capture the return code of Open_connection and take action based on that?